# how to nest AND/OR within an sql statement

Tags: sql, database

I have a table with a date column(`date`) and integer column(`hour`(range 6-20)) for marking  the date and hour of an event.

I want to display all entries of events that have not occurred yet. i.e. all those entries whose `date>curdate()` and for those whose `curdate()=date`, we compare the `EXTRACT(hour FROM current_time())` with hour and display those having extracted_current_hour < `hour`.

This is looking a bit nested/complex and I cant seem to figure it out. Help me guys.

Comment: My first hint would be to imagine how you would write/nest that in any programming language you happen to know, and just write it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements the where clause would look something like this: 
`WHERE date>curdate() OR (curdate()=date AND extracted_current_hour < hour)`
Notice the () around `curdate()=date AND extracted_current_hour < hour`

Comment: Oh god, why didn't I think of that earlier. Thanks buddy. I was over complicating things in my mind when such a simple solution existed.